# I need specific WordPress photo gallery plugin with multiple categories

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am looking for a WordPress gallery plugin that I can have multiple categories that is exactly like the gallery from this site http://www.naturephotographers.net/enter.html. I need a gallery that I can separate into multiple categories, labeled,  where I can click on a picture, then opens up to a slideshow. If anyone knows a plugin please share with me as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Why the requirement of plugin ? You can do this using custom taxonomy and custom categories with ease !!

Comment: Because for this case I can't perform any custom theme development. That would become the first thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try those plugins,

--This two plugin is from WordPress plugin repository.

> Categories Images By Muhammad Said El Zahlan
>   Categories Multiple Images By Lior Broshi, Binternet

This Plugin is from Outside:

> Responsive WordPress Portfolio Plugin with Categories by wonderplugin.